# セクタは誰が決めたのですか

Tags: filesystems

セクタは誰が決めたのですか

- ハードディスク設計者
- パーティション設計者
- OS設計者

プログラムではどのようなパーティションでもセクタサイズは同じですか

osではクラスタ単位で扱うそうですがOSの代わりにセクタにアクセスする方法はありますか

もし、クラスタよりも小さいデータを書き込んだらパディングされるのですか

データ復旧プログラムですが概略だけでも私にも書けるようになりますか

Comment: 質問の背景として、どのような問題を抱えているのか書いていただくと回答がつきやすいと思います。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **セクタは誰が決めたのですか**

誰が決めたかまではわかりません。一番最初にハードディスクを作ったIBMが決めた規格かもしれません。
個人の特定でなければ、ハードディスク設計者がセクタを定義しアクセスとキャッシュの管理を行っています。
OSは、ハードディスク設計者が規格に沿って作成したレジスタと命令により書き込み読み出しを行っています。

---

- **プログラムではどのようなパーティションでもセクタサイズは同じですか**

ハードディスク設計者が規格に沿ってセクタを定義しているのでパーティションによってサイズが変わることはありません。フォーマット時に設定できるアロケーションユニットサイズはクラスタのサイズのことです。

---

- **osではクラスタ単位で扱うそうですがOSの代わりにセクタにアクセスする方法はありますか**

自分自身でハードディスクのレジスタにアクセスしたりコマンドを送ることができればかのうです。が、OSがある環境で直接アクセスすることができるかは、試したことがないのでわかりません。

---

- **もし、クラスタよりも小さいデータを書き込んだらパディングされるのですか**

レジスタに書き込みやコマンドを送るその通信はビット数ぴったりでなければいけません。何かしらの値がパディングされています。詳しくはOSのカーネルを読むしかないかと思います。

---

- **データ復旧プログラムですが概略だけでも私にも書けるようになりますか**

えぇ。それはもちろん努力次第で

Answer (score 4):

セクタを作ったのはだれか？挙がっている３つの選択肢の中からあえて選ぶなら
・OS設計者
でしょう。しかし、セクタという管理機構が考え出された時代はコンピューターメーカーがハードウェアもOSもひとまとめにして作っていたのでハードディスク設計者との区分が明確にあるわけではないです。
参考のため、じゃぁセクタ以外の管理方法は？というと、メインフレーム等で使われていたCKD(count-key-data)という管理機構があります。これは利用者が自分で入出力ブロックのサイズを指定します。（80カラムのコードだから6400バイトブロックとかそんな風です）

どのようなパーティションでもセクタサイズは同じですか？
過去には光磁気ディスクとかセクタサイズが512byteではない装置も存在していましたし、ハードディスクは物理セクタを4Kbyteに移行中です。現在のセクタ（クラスタ）サイズというものも管理効率の便宜で決まっているものなのでいつまでも同じということはないと思います。パーティションごとに違う可能性があると考えるのが妥当でしょう。

クラスタサイズより小さいデータを書き込んだら．．．
そのエリアはつまり使用されていないエリアとして無駄になります。今日的なOSはファイルを作成する際に確保したスペースをクリアするのでパディングされていると思って問題ないです。これは、過去にそこにあったデータを読みだされることが無いようにセキュリティ面から行われます。

データ復旧プログラムを作ることはできるか
時代が移るにつれ、効率よりセキュリティと言ったものが重視されるようになっており、全般的に復旧は難しくなっていると思います。実際に復旧できるかどうかはケースバイケースとしか言えません。

Answer (score 0):

質問があいまいです。そのうえであえて回答するとしたら、

ハードディスクのセクタはハードディスク設計者が決定します。ファイルシステムのクラスタはファイルシステム設計者が決定します。パーティションやOSは関係ありません。
各々の用語が何に由来するものなのかもっと詳しく知る必要があるのではないでしょうか。